# Calling a JavaScript function from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I have a php script that is a bit of a mess and after a form entry, I need to get an address, and display it on a google map.  The html and php is crammed into the same script so I essentially need to call the JavaScript as the PHP is happening.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: No; php 'happens' on the server, JavaScript 'happens' in the browser (client-side). There is [server-side JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript) but, and this is entirely personal and not provided with reference/objective tests, I'd recommend against trying to use it for this.

Comment: I think you kind of miss the point of how PHP and Javascript work. Do you have any code so that we get a better idea of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you simply calling a function that needs to be displayed when you are done or do you need to get data back and do something with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PHP executed by the server and returns the full response to the browser. JavaScript in the page is then executed by the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can POST your from to a different frame (or iframe), so your page would not reload. The response of your PHP file which comes back to that frame can contain JavaScript code, which will be executed. Something like:

```
echo('<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Executed on client side"); </script>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call Javascript functions from PHP. You can set the Javascript to run when the page loads instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
var userAddress = "<?php echo $_POST['address']; ?>";
doSomethingWithAddress(userAddress);
</script>
```

If that code is on the page which you are POSTing the address to, it would take the address from the user, and write it into a javascript tag. The PHP will get executed first on the server, before building the HTML document. This new document has the variable available to the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would go about doing that, but this seems like a good place to start looking:
http://code.google.com/intl/en/